# Can it be easier to toggle show/hide ignored tags on the review page?

Tags: feature-request, review, ignored-tags

I've recently started using the review tab and there is one thing that sort of annoys me about it.

I have a lot of ignored tags. This normally doesn't matter as I can always browse questions by tag and the homepage always has an abundance of questions with tags I am interested in.

The review tab is a different story. As I've worked my way through the tabs, the pool of non-ignored questions/answers gets smaller and smaller until I'm left with...

[image: Somethings missing...]

If I'm reviewing posts for proper formatting, spelling, flagging for off-topic, not an answer, etc. tags aren't really that important anymore.

So pretty much anytime I want to switch between /questions and /review, I need to go to my profile, then the preferences tab and uncheck that checkbox or take the shortcut of using Firebug to remove the `display:none`.

I could just switch to reviewing something else for awhile, but if there are still posts left to review, why shouldn't it be easier for me to go through them?

Should there be an option on the /review page itself to show/hide ignored tags? Or am I just going about this whole review thing wrong?

Comment: I would much prefer a toggle. For example I just asked a Mac question at SU and cannot see it because I have all `mac` tags ignored. Simply toggling it is **much** preferable to having to remove the tag from the ignore list and then having to add it back later.

Comment: For some reason I can't firebug it on SO--all traces of ignored questions are gone. Exactly what did you firebug? Which class? $('.tagged-ignored') is empty on SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the big reason we dislike the "hide ignored tags" option - it is handled client side, you explicitly said you never want to see these questions.

If we were to add a "ignore my hidden tags" option on "/review" should we also do that in the "flag" section? And the suggested edit section? And in search?

I am really not sure what to do here, but adding another option seems risky.

Comment: To be fair, I said I never wanted to see those questions because I'm not able to answer them or I have no interest in their subject matter. Wanting to be able to fix the spelling, formatting, etc. on them is different. If I'm hindered in wanting to improve the quality of the site outside my own little area, that seems a little... odd. It doesn't have to be a different option, why couldn't it just be the same one but with a checkbox that's easily accessible on the review page?

Comment: For that matter, why not add it to the search page? Something I've run across in the past is that if I search for questions regarding a jQuery plugin, the majority of the time I don't really care what the server side language is. Yet quite a few of the questions have a language tag attached, I don't get to see all of them. I usually end up following the same process to unhide the tags just to make sure I didn't miss something that could have been helpful.

Comment: @Brandon not strictly against adding this checkbox **if** you happen to have ignored tags and that pref set. But I feel this is a bit of a different feature request. A lot more open to just giving you that checkbox everywhere if you have "hide tags = true" ... not sure how Jeff / the community feels about this

Comment: That would work, but just another thought, why not handle it the way Google handles their blocked sites? Sort all the blocked (in this case ignored) results to the bottom, and just have a line that says "You are hiding X results. Click to show". No persistence or anything would be necessary, just a little bit of extra jQuery. You'd need that jQuery anyways to show the questions, unless you want to make the user refresh the page :P

Comment: @waffles: For some reason, on MSO, .tagged-ignored is made half-transparent, while on SO it seems to be either (a) handled server-side, or (b) jQuery-magically deleted. I was trying to userscript/bookmarklet this, but SO seems to remove all traces of ignored questions. What's the actual implementation and how is it bypassed?

Comment: have a look at your secret user setting on meta and SO @Manishearth (dig through your user profile)

Comment: @waffles: Aah, thanks. :) I'll script this the moment I finish an answer on Phy.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarklet!

```
javascript:(function(){if($('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display")=="none"){$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display","block");}else{$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display","none")}return false;})();
```

This toggles the hidden ones. If you've set it to just blur the posts, this won't do anything, you need

```
javascript:(function(){return false;})();
```

If you want to have both functionalities at once (different sites, different settings):

```
javascript:(function(){if($('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display")=="none"){$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display","block");}else{$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("display","none")}if($('.tagged-ignored').css("opacity")==0.5){$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("opacity",1);}else{$('.tagged-ignored-hidden').css("opacity",0.5)}return false;})();
```