# Review page says "1 post" but nothing is shown?

Tags: bug, review

I was browsing through the tabs to see if there was anything new to review and no posts were showing up but when I went past "low quality posts" I noticed that it said "1 post" at the top but hadn't seen anything below it, so I went back to the tab and sure enough there was nothing there:

[image: post-that-does-not-exist]

As I continue to refresh the low quality posts tab, it keeps saying there is still 1 post but nothing is showing.

Comment: Do you have any ignored tags?

Comment: This feature request might be of interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112616/can-it-be-easier-to-toggle-show-hide-ignored-tags-on-the-review-page

Comment: That has happened to me several times as well, and I have no ignored tags.

Comment: This is still happening. At one time the "first answers" tab showed 1 post, the "low quality posts" tab showed 1 post, and the "late answers" showed 3 posts, all tabs not actually showing anything. Just to reiterate, I do not have ignored tags blocked, so it shouldn't be hiding anything. Where are these posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently not the only cause (or the cause for this specific case), but one way for this to happen is that you have ignored tags and the post is (correctly) hidden from you for that reason.  It still says that there is one post to review because, well, there is.

I have confirmed this by going [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day), ignoring the tag [skyrim](/questions/tagged/skyrim), refreshing, and observing that the "8 Posts" at the top does not change even though the page now only shows 4 posts.

The "Hide Ignored Tags" option that I am talking about is located at Profile -> Preferences.

[image]